# Issues adding UITableView inside a UIViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

So I'm attempting to build a single screen app where I start with a UIViewController. On top of that there is a UITextfield, a button, and a UITableView.

Essentially the intended functionality of the app is for a user to type a word into the UITextField, hit a button, and have it show up on the UITableView.

I never have problems doing this when the the button appends the UITextField entries to a UITableViewController on a different screen, but for some reason I'm having problems with a UITableView embedded on the UIViewController... On my storyboard I did link the UITableView as a delegate and datasource of the UIViewController so that shouldn't be the problem.

Any ideas? My code is posted below.

```
import UIKit

var groupList:[String] = []

class ExistingGroups: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{

@IBOutlet weak var addGroup: UITextField!


@IBAction func addGroupButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    var error = ""

    if addGroup.text == "" {

        error = "Please enter a Group!"
    } else {

        groupList.append(addGroup.text)

    }

    if error != "" {

        var alert = UIAlertController(title:"Error In Form", message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

        }))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

    addGroup.text = ""


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    addGroup.placeholder = "Enter Group Name"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func touchesBegan(touches:NSSet, withEvent event:UIEvent)
{
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return groupList.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView:UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupcell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = groupList[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}



}
```

Comment: Did you reload your tableview when user finish input?

Comment: You need to set the UITextFieldDelegate to self and reload the table when user enters the text

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem now is that for the self.tableView.reloadData(); line of code, I am getting an error "(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int' does not have a member named 'reloadData'"

Comment: Also for the UITextField "addGroup" I did drag to the UIViewController and set as delegate on the storyboard. I also added your line of code as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Try to use `self.tableView!.reloadData()`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all create an `IBOutlet` for your table view this way :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

var groupList = [String]()
@IBOutlet weak var addGroup: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!  //<<-- TableView Outlet

// Rest of your code..

}
```

After that do this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupcell")

    self.addGroup.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

After that you can `reload` your tableView once the element is added into `groupList`. Here you can do this:

```
@IBAction func addGroupButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Your Code

    } else {

        groupList.append(addGroup.text)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

   //Your Code

}
```

And Update this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("groupcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = self.groupList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

And you can check final code which I created for you is [HERE](http://pastebin.com/BPLbnsvL).

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Totally solved my problem, thanks guys.

Comment: Thank you guy for fixing my problem

Comment: happy to help you..:)

Comment: Wow, I was stuck on something like this all morning and this post helped me out tremendously. Thank you @DharmeshKheni

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    addGroup.delegate = self // You can do this in storyboard also
    addGroup.placeholder = "Enter Group Name"
}    

@IBAction func addGroupButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.view.endEditing(true)

        var error = ""

        if addGroup.text == "" {

            error = "Please enter a Group!"
        } else {

            groupList.append(addGroup.text)

           //reload the table after adding text to array
            self.tableView.reloadData();

        }

        if error != "" {

            var alert = UIAlertController(title:"Error In Form", message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)

            }))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)

        }

        addGroup.text = ""


    }
```